# Generate a report over an AdSense account and outputs the results to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, adsense-api

I suck at Google apps script and need to import an AdSense report into a google spreadsheet. I tried the sample available in the reference guide of the
Google Apps Script for advanced services, but I couldn't get it to work.

The sample for the code.gs is available like this:

```
function generateReport(adClientId) {
var today = new Date();
var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

var timezone = Session.getTimeZone();
var startDate = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
var endDate = Utilities.formatDate(today, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

var report = AdSense.Reports.generate(startDate, endDate, {
  filter: ['AD_CLIENT_ID==' + escapeFilterParameter(adClientId)],
  metric: ['PAGE_VIEWS', 'AD_REQUESTS', 'AD_REQUESTS_COVERAGE', 'CLICKS',
           'AD_REQUESTS_CTR', 'COST_PER_CLICK', 'AD_REQUESTS_RPM',
           'EARNINGS'],
  dimension: ['DATE'],
  sort: ['+DATE'],
});

if (report.rows) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create('AdSense Report');
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var headers = report.headers.map(function(header) {
    return header.name;
  });
  sheet.appendRow(headers);

  sheet.getRange(2, 1, report.rows.length, headers.length)
      .setValues(report.rows);

  Logger.log('Report spreadsheet created: %s',
      spreadsheet.getUrl());

  Logger.log('No rows returned.');
```

How do I make it call the report?

Comment: What is the error you are experiencing? You can check the logs in the Logs and Execution Transcript.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this in the google apps script console.
https://www.google.com/script/start/
or go to google drive -> New -> More -> Google Apps Scripts

Then click on Services and enable AdSense Management API service.

Then Paste the code & Run

for more details, here is the walkthroug https://youtu.be/OHSNb9UnvPk

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32196543)

Answer (score -2):

if your AdSense data resides in BigQuery then you can use a service like [Cirkulate](https://cirkulate.com), which does exactly this type of database to spreadsheet export in a recurring fashion. Set a SQL query(or queries), set refresh schedule and add recipients who need to be emailed the spreadsheet. Thats it.

Disclosure: Just to be clear about affiliations, I am the founder of Cirkulate

Comment: You must *clearly* disclose your affiliation ***in the post*** when linking to your own products or projects. Otherwise, your posts may be treated as “astro-turfing” or spam.